# Github instead of uploading my application uploads another application

Tags: git, github, file-upload, git-bash

Github has been acting very strangely for several days:

1. It does not upload my Node.js application.
2. Instead, it uploads the older draft of my application that is not even in the directory that I am uploading; it is somewhere else in my computer and has a different name.  However, on the Github it gets the name of the application that I tried to upload.
3. After it uploads the application, on the commit tab it shows 22 commits, which all of them are from the older drafts of the same application and from my previous applications, which I have already deleted from Github.

Prior to uploading my application, I deleted all remotes in all directories, including remote origin.  I don't know why I am having this problem, and I can't figure out how to solve it.

Comment: What commands have you been running? What directory have you executed those commands in? What is the `git status` of your repository? Do you have the remote set correctly?

Comment: Hi Zach, thank you for your help.  I uploaded it to the Git directory `origin master`.  First I removed `origin` then I added the regular commands: `git remote add origin` and `git push -u origin master`.  Just now to fix the problem I added the following command: `rm -rf .git/` apparently this deleted all the 22 commits, but now I cannot push the file to repository after I deleted it; when I type `git push origin master` it says `error: src refspec master does not match any.`

Comment: When you delete `.git` you are deleting all of the files that git uses for that repository locally. You deleted the history of those commits that you just made and the remote host is no longer set. As far as git knows, this isn't even a repository anymore. Your best option would be to save the code somewhere, make a fresh clone of the repository, reapply changes, then commit and push the new changes.

Comment: Please explain what do you mean by save the code somewhere?  To where?  And what do you mean by make a fresh clone of the repository?

Comment: I mean save the code you currently have in another location so that you don't lose changes that haven't been pushed yet. Delete your current repository and clone another copy from your remote. Then make your changes to that new repo and commit and push there.

Comment: I completely removed the code from Github.  I have the code only in my computer.  I cannot figure out how to put it back into Github again; `git push -u origin master` does not work anymore.  I did create a new repository and and a new remote origin.

Comment: You need to create a new repo and run `git init` locally in your repo directory. Then add the remote host and commit and push.

Comment: The `commit` and `push` commands do not work.  When I type `git commit -m "first commit"`, it states: `[master fatal: unable to read tree 6fa3be2262c1c8598282b2b1ac284ba8af631555`  And when I type `git push -u origin master` it states: `error: Could not read 11c5347dafcd53470726ba87a06976c406185061`
`fatal: Failed to traverse parents of commit d9e44a39f452b7213d9e68b5b20c5539cb1861c2`
`fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly` And when I type `git push` it states: `No refs in common and none specified; doing nothing.`
`Perhaps you should specify a branch such as 'master'.`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem. There was a hidden `.git` file at the root directory of my code that messed up everything, which was a leftover from my previous draft of the code.  The file is visible in Windows folder, but not in Sublime Text.  I did the following:

1. I deleted the repository on Github and created a new repository.
2. I deleted the hidden `.git` file on Windows folder where the code that I want to upload is located.
3. I changed the Gitbash directory to the directory of the code that I want to upload.
4. I typed the command `init` on Gitbash to create a new hidden `.git` file for my upload code.
5. I typed the regular git commands to add and push origin master, and then I typed `git push`.

You can see the content of the hidden `.git` file from Windows folder by double clicking the `.git` file, and then see inside the content of the files with no extensions, such as `config` using `Notepad++` code editor.